# Class list is showing error. I am using swatch to select variant I want to convert jQuery to pure javascript to select?

Tags: javascript, shopify

```
 <script>
  jQuery('.swatch[data-option-index="{{ option_index }}"] .{{ value | handle }}').removeClass('soldout').addClass('available').find(':radio').removeAttr('disabled');
</script>
```

I have been struggling to convert this to pure javascript.
I have tried the below code

```
  <script>
  document.querySelector('.swatch[data-option-index="{{ option_index }}"].{{ value | handle }}').classList.remove('soldout').classList.add('available').find(':radio').removeAttribute('disabled');
</script>
```

But I m getting **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined** 
Please help me to solve this issue. I am new to javascript

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

```
.swatch[data-option-index="{{ option_index }}"].{{ value | handle }}
```

Try with this

```
.swatch[data-option-index="{{ option_index }}"] .{{ value | handle }}
```

Comment: I did not see that gap between the "." Thank you very much. It saved my time alot